using media query in flutter is good or bad
I am new to flutter and still learning it. I have a noob question about using media query in flutter. As far as i know "MediaQuery.of(context).size" is used responsive sizing. but all of sudden i noticed that it rebuild the current context. If i am developing a chat app where i will use MediaQuery.of(context).size for bottom sheet to adjust height according to keyboard then it will rebuild whole tree again and again, if i am not wrong.
What will be the best practice for such type of scenarios. Is there any other alternate?
Thank you in advance.

It's very common practice. Don't worry about it. Develop using it first, then optimize if you have to (you probably won't) later.

@MatthewTrent Thank you for your reply. I am currently working on an app that have chat rooms. and each room has n numbers of users where they can comment n number of times. is it a good practice for this scenario?

Yes in fact correct it is, yes. (sorry, min character count, lol)

Refer to this

@DhafinRayhan thank u for the information

According to this documentation Use this MediaQuery.sizeOf(context); as it only rebuild the context when this specific attribute changes.
